# How is Play! framework different than ZK Frame work

Tags: android, web-services, playframework, zk

I want the difference in terms of learning curve, usability, efficiency and situations in which they should be used. I want to create webservice with JSON,XML responses and use it from an Android as well as use it on web site.

I am good in ZK but play! is completely new for me.

Thanks & regards,
Aman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zk and Play! are really 2 very different things. The main differences between the 2 that I think of:

- ZK focuses on UI components — much like ICEfaces and other similar frameworks — while Play! doesn't **at all**; there are *no* UI components in Play!
- In my opinion Play offers a different philosophy more than anything else compared to most other Java/scala web frameworks; it's a back to basics approach that abolishes server-side state (which is the complete opposite of ZK) and everything that comes with it. At the same time, it's still a full-featured stack with everything integrated into it; you won't have to spend hours gathering your dependencies.

I've used ZK briefly in the past and in my opinion Play! is easier to pick up than ZK, even though that's a very relative judgement. There's a big difference in approach here though, and if you're looking to create a JSON/XML based web service then Play! seems much preferable over ZK because:

1. You don't need UI components, so that's the main selling point of ZK out the window
2. It's going to be very easy to define and maintain your services using Play's routing mechanism
3. Implementing your services is going to be about as easy and straightforward as it could ever be (depending on your specific requirements, naturally)

The disadvantages of Play! really depend on your specific requirements; but one issue that comes to mind is building web services that integrate heavily with more traditional and legacy services (such as EJB, for example). Since Play! applications don't really adhere to any of the common Java EE standards (even though they can run in a Java EE container), you might end up writing a lot of integration code yourself rather than having the container do it for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I did not get wat u want to explain in last paragraph. I am not JAVA boy :)

Comment: An attempt to clarify: [JEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Enterprise_Edition) applications will be deployed in a JEE container (such as Weblogic, Websphere, GlassFish, etc.). When you write another application using the JEE stack, it's usually very easy to use previous services that were programmed independently from your application (e.g. via [EJB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean])). Play is not designed as a JEE technology, so it might not always be easy to integrate existing JEE services with a Play application.